# How to split 3 spaces ligature in lstlisting

Tags: listings, ligatures

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=PHP,breaklines]
$a === $b;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

How to show spaces separately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=PHP,breaklines,columns=flexible]
$a === $b;
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=PHP,breaklines,basicstyle=\ttfamily]
$a === $b;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can abuse the `literate` key to break the ligature.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=PHP,breaklines]
$a === $b;
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=PHP,breaklines,literate={===}{={}={}=}3] % <--- !
$a === $b;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```